# How to query an n:n adjacency list map in DynamoDB without using scan

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm trying to model a cataloging system in DynamodDB. It has "Catalogs" which contains "Collections". Each "Collection" can be tagged by many "Tags".

In an RDBMS I would create a table "Catalogs" with a 1:n relationship with "Collections". "Collections" would have an n:n with "Tags" as a Collection can have multiple Tags and a Tag can belong to multiple Collections.

The queries I want to run are:

1) Get all catalogs

2) Get catalog by ID

3) Get collections by catalog ID

I read on AWS I can use the adjacency list map design (because I have the n:n with "Tags"). So here is my table structure:

```
PK         SK         name    
cat-1      cat-1      Sales Catalog
cat-1      col-1      Sales First Collection
cat-1      col-2      Sales Second Collection
cat-2      cat-2      Finance Catalog 
tag-1      tag-1      Recently Added Tag
col-1      tag-1      (collection, tag relationship)
```

The problem here is I have to use a scan which I understand to be inefficient in order to get all "Catalogs" because a query's PK has to be an '=' and not a 'Begins With'.

The only thing I can think of is creating another attribute like "GSI_PK" and add "Catalog_1" when the PK is cat-1 and the SK is cat-1, "Catalog_2" when the PK is cat-2 and SK is cat-2. I've never really see this done so I'm not sure if it's the way to go and it takes some maintenance if I ever want to change IDs.

Any ideas how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, you can have the PK be the type of the object and the SK be a uuid. A record would look like this `{ PK: "Catalog", SK: "uuid", ...other catalog fields }`. You can then do a get all catalogs by doing a query on the PK = Catalog.

To store the associations you can have a GSI on two fields `sourcePK` and `relatedPK` where you could store records that associate things. To associate an object you would create a record like e.g. `{ PK: "Association", SK: "uuid", sourcePK: "category-1", relatedPK: "collection-1", ... other data on the association }`. To find objects associated with the "Catalog" with id 1, you would do a query on the GSI where sourcePK = catalog-1.

With this setup you need to be careful about hot keys and should make sure you never have more than 10GBs of data under the same partition key in a table or index.

Comment: Ok I was thinking along the same lines, adding a type column and creating a GSI on that column.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through it. I'll use GraphQL SDL to layout the design of the data model & queries but you can just apply the same concepts to DynamoDB directly.

Thinking data model first we will have something like:

```
type Catalog {
  id: ID!
  name: String

  # Use a DynamoDB query on the **Collection** table 
  # where the **catalogId = $ctx.source.id**. Use a GSI or make catalogId the PK.
  collections: [Collection]
}
type Collection {
  id: ID!
  name: String

  # Use a DynamoDB query on the **CollectionTag** table where
  # the **collectionId = $ctx.source.id**. Use a GSI or make the collectionId the PK.
  tags: [CollectionTag]
}
# The "association map" idea as a GraphQL type. The underlying table has a collectionId and tagId.
# Create objects of this type to associate a collection and tag in the many to many relationship.
type CollectionTag {
  # Do a GetItem on the **Collection** table where **id = $ctx.source.collectionId**
  collection: Collection

  # Do a GetItem on the **Tag** table where **id = $ctx.source.tagId**
  tag: Tag
}
type Tag {
  id: ID!
  name: String

  # Use a DynamoDB query on teh **CollectionTag** table where
  # the **tagId = $ctx.source.id**. If collectionId is the PK then make a GSI where this tagId is the PK.
  collections: [CollectionTag]
}

# Root level queries
type Query {
  # GetItem to **Catalog** table where **id = $ctx.args.id**
  getCatalog(id: ID!): Catalog

  # Scan to **Catalog** table. As long as you don't care about ordering on a filed in particular then
  # this will likely be okay at the top level. If you only want all catalogs where "arePublished = 1",
  # for example then we would likely change this.
  allCatalogs: [Catalog]

  # Note: You don't really need a getCollectionsByCatalogId(catalogId: ID!) at the top level because you can
  # use `query { getCatalog(id: "***") { collections { ... } } }` which is effectively the same thing.
  # You could add another field here if having it at the top level was a requirement
  getCollectionsByCatalogId(catalogId: ID!): [Collection]
}
```

> Note: Everywhere I use `[Collection]` or `[Catalog]` etc above you should use a `CollectionConnection`, `CatalogConnection`, etc wrapper type to enable pagination.

Comment: So I want an n:n relationship table where all items are stored in one table. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html. In the root query you have allCatalogs and you mention scan which I'm doing now but I understand scanning is inefficient in dynamo db and it would be better to use a query

Comment: So basically how would I get all catalogs by querying the hash key in dynamodb in an adjacency list n:n mapped table

Comment: Responded in new answer